# Select correct language field in XML parsed file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a XML file in the format below.

```
<movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">
 <movie key="1">
  <movieId>1</movieId>
  <movieTitle>Alien</movieTitle>
  <movieDate>1979</movieDate>
  <movieUrl>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/</movieUrl>
 </movie>
 <movie key="2">
  <movieId>2</movieId>
  <movieTitle>Robocop</movieTitle>
  <movieDate>1987</movieDate>
  <movieUrl>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093870/</movieUrl>
 </movie>
```

Using jQuery I am able to loop through this and get the info from the films using code:

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
 //find every movie
 jQuery(xml).find("movie").each(function()
 {
  movieId = jQuery(this).find("movieId").text();
  movieTitle= jQuery(this).find("movieTitle").text();
 });
}
```

This all works perfectly , however I wanted to add some multi-language support in it but wanted to keep all languages in the same file instead of having to worry about multiple versions of it all over the place. So I modified the XML to the below, note the new lang="pt" on the title:

```
<movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">
 <movie key="1">
  <movieId>1</movieId>
  <movieTitle lang="en">Alien</movieTitle>
  <movieTitle lang="pt">Alien - O 8.º Passageiro</movieTitle>
  <movieDate>1979</movieDate>
  <movieUrl>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/</movieUrl>
 </movie>
 <movie key="2">
  <movieId>2</movieId>
  <movieTitle lang="en">Robocop</movieTitle>
  <movieTitle lang="pt">Robocop - O polícia do futuro</movieTitle>
  <movieDate>1987</movieDate>
  <movieUrl>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093870/</movieUrl>
 </movie>
```

In my code I am setting a language var in Javascript such as

```
<script>var languageCode = "pt";</script>
```

Now when I am looping through the movies I want to use this code to work out what title to use, and if there isn't one to fall back on the `en` title, which will always be there.

I have tried using the filter in jQuery but not too sure how it works, for example this doesn't work

```
 movieNameObj = jQuery(this).find("movieTitle");
 movieNameObj.filter(function() { 
     return jQuery(this).attr('lang:ro'); }).each(function() {
         console.log("Matched RO");
     });
```

**Update**

Using the below code I have got it working, however is there any way to optimise it?

```
//find movieName in correct language
jQuery(this).find("movieTitle").each(function()
{
    movieNameLang = jQuery(this).attr("lang");
    if(movieNameLang == "en")
    {
        movieName = jQuery(this).text();
    }
    if(movieNameLang == languageCode)
    {
        movieName = jQuery(this).text();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you can drop the `find`.

```
//find movieName in correct language
jQuery("movieTitle", this).each(function()
{
    movieNameLang = jQuery(this).attr("lang");
    if(movieNameLang == "en")
    {
        movieName = jQuery(this).text();
    }
    if(movieNameLang == languageCode)
    {
        movieName = jQuery(this).text();
    }
});
```